# Simple form of looping formula that takes a long time

Tags: excel, vba

Please help. I did calculation through VBA with formula below.
maybe my repetition is confusing :(

```
For i = 1 To 200
Cells(i + 10, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheets("PETA").range("D" & i + 1 & ":I" & i + 1)) 'T1.s1
Cells(i + 10, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheets("PETA").range("J" & i + 1 & ":O" & i + 1)) 'T1.s2
Cells(i + 10, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheets("PETA").range("P" & i + 1 & ":U" & i + 1)) 'T1.s3
```

.... to .... `Cells(i + 10, 105)`

its turns out that at moment of run, this formula works takes a long time. is there a simple formula for repetition like the formula I made above? all looked good when working under 50 cells, but after that, the CPU capacity began to be used

Comment: First, you could optimize performance by changing worksheet calculation mode into manual, turning of screenupdating, events and alerts. Second, which adds even more speed is not working directly on the worksheet, but rather copy data into an array and make the necessary edits on the array, which is much faster as it happens inside of memory.

Comment: you are right, calculation mode into manuals, turning of screenupdating, events and alerts can reduce memory performance. however, is there any code that is simpler than the line of code above..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to a large number of cells, one cell at a time, is very inefficient.  Instead, first create a temporary array, and write the results to the array.  Then, transfer the contents of the array to your worksheet all at once.

```
'set the source worksheet
Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Set sourceWorksheet = Sheets("PETA")

'set the source range
Dim sourceRange As Range
Set sourceRange = sourceWorksheet.Range("D2:WQ201")

'create a temporary array to hold the results
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tempArray() As Variant
ReDim tempArray(1 To sourceRange.Rows.Count, 1 To sourceRange.Columns.Count \ 6)
With Application
    For i = LBound(tempArray, 1) To UBound(tempArray, 1)
        For j = LBound(tempArray, 2) To UBound(tempArray, 2)
            'Debug.Print sourceRange.Resize(1, 6).Offset(i - 1, j * 6 - 6).Address
            tempArray(i, j) = .CountA(sourceRange.Resize(1, 6).Offset(i - 1, j * 6 - 6))
        Next j
    Next i
End With

'transfer the contents of the temporary array to the active worksheet
Range("E11").Resize(UBound(tempArray, 1), UBound(tempArray, 2)).Value = tempArray
```

Comment: this is what I mean!!. very fast processing and simple form of code. :).
can you explain a little about how a numbers are located at `tempArray` and if values in `Dim tempArray(1 To 200, 1 To 102)` change, for example `x=100 -- Dim tempArray(1 To x, 1 To 102)`. thank you for the quick response

Comment: I have edited my post to amend the code.  You'll notice that the entire source range is assigned to `sourceRange`, and that `tempArray` has been allocated storage space dynamically.  So there's no need to manually change any of the dimensions.

Comment: amazing, I was very impressed by a code line. is like flowing water. clear and enlighten my limitations in vba. `dim` to `redim` _* that's new to me_. once again, thank you @Domenic for the useful knowledge, :) +1

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I could help.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Very often these slowdowns are caused by the spreadsheet recalculating after each statement which changes the spreadsheet (and you look to have 600 of them in that loop).

Just before the `For i` line put

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

which turns off automatic calculation.

When all the copying about has finished, add:

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

which turns it back on.